# If statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is this code correct?

```
if(!($('textarea: name').val().length == 0)) {
alert("test");
}
```

I want to check if there is something written or not inside the textarea field in the form? I ask because it's not working!?

Comment: Did you bind this function to textarea event? Because if you do then you don't need use $('textarea: name') selector, you'll have already 'this'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(!($('textarea').val().length == 0))` will work if you have only one `textarea` element in your page. I think what you were trying to do with that `:name` selector was select a specific `textarea` based on its name, in which case you need:

`$('textarea[name=yourName]')`

Comment: Nice! That worked as I wanted, but I was using the ID of the textarea not the name from the beginning. ID not working like this $('textarea[#yourName]')?

Comment: You could do `$('textarea#yourName')` or just `$('#yourName')`. The second one will perform faster.

Comment: Yes, @justis's method is perfect. However, just so you're clear on what I was doing, `$('textarea')` will select all `textarea` elements in the document. If you want to select an element by it's `id`, you use the `#`. If you want to use the `class`, you use a `.`, and if you want to use another attribute you do it like this: `$('textarea[name=theName]')`.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing your closing parens in your `if` statement. Try this:

```
 if(!( $('textarea: name').val().length == 0 ))
   {alert("test");}
```

There may be other jQuery selector issues.

Comment: Also the selector. What is `$('textarea: name')` supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks! Closing parens in place!

Answer (score 2):

Since a length of 0 is "falsy", you can simplify your test to using just `.length`:

```
if ($('textarea[name=foo]').val().length) {
    alert(true);
} else {
    alert(false);
}
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQfu4/1/) where you can play with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('textarea: name').val().length > 0) {
    // do something if textbox has content
}
```